# Cannot update a timestamp column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, syntax-error

I was recommended the following stored procedure to audit a login table.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE ApplicationLogin 
     @Username NVARCHAR(255), 
     @IpAddress NVARCHAR(255)
 AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @UserID INT;

     BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

     SET @UserID = (SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE Username = @Username);

     IF @UserID > 0
     BEGIN
         UPDATE User 
         SET LastLogin = GETDATE() 
         WHERE UserID = @UserID;
     END

    INSERT INTO UserLogger (Username, UserID, TimeStamp)
    VALUES (@Username, @UserID, @Timestamp);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    SELECT @UserID    
END
```

However I can't make it work for some syntax errors that I can't figure out.

The `User` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [UserID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [LastLogin] [TIMESTAMP] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
)
```

The `Audit` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLogger]
(
    [UserID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [TS] [TIMESTAMP] NULL,
    [IpAddress] [NCHAR](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I get an error

> Cannot update a timestamp column

which I don't see why.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

`timestamp` is not what you think it is.  It is some sort of internal representation of the row address.  [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is an explanation.

Use `datetime` or `datetime2` to fix your problem.

This is made all the more confusing, because `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` doesn't return a timestamp.